# MySQL alter table change column throw error if rows change

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, alter-table

This question might probably have been asked somewhere but I just can't seem to find it after much searching.

I have a basic question on how I can prevent the last SQL statement in my code below from executing if it caused any row/data in the table to change.

```
$query = 'SELECT pdt_code FROM `Products`';
$stmt = $con->query($query);
while ($obj = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $pdt_code[] = $obj['pdt_code'];
}

$args = implode(',', 
            array_map(function($el) { 
                return '('.implode(',', $el).')'; 
            },
            array_chunk(array_fill(0, count($pdt_code), '?'), count($pdt_code))
            )
        );

$query = 'ALTER TABLE `MapProduct` CHANGE product_code product_code SET '.$args.' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL';
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($pdt_code); // how do I prevent this line from executing if it causes the data in table `MapProduct` to change?
```

I am trying to execute this from PHP where I query another table for updates to product codes and update the `SET()` accordingly. However, I had a horrific experience of losing all my data because the update was not properly executed and all the data in `product_code` got wiped.

Comment: WHY do you need to automate ALTER TABLE?

Comment: @davidstrachan Because the table where products are stored will be modified from time to time. And if the SET fails to be updated accordingly, any new inserts will be rejected.

Comment: You should not use set in this case. Use a lookup table and a foreign key to restrict the list product codes. In that case all you need to do is to insert a new record into your product codes lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

Although mysql's SET data type can be used to restrict list of values being entered. However, it is not flexible and requires an alter table to update the list of values. If you frequently have to do this - and if you build a functionality to do that, then you need to do this frequently - then the SET data type is simply not for you.

I would create a separate table for product types and I would simply reference this table with a foreign key from your mapproduct table. This way adding a new product type to the allowed list inly requires an insert statement.